# Может ли наречие "по-настоящему" быть вводным словом?

Tags: вводные-слова

Обычно  "по-настоящему" является обстоятельством и и не обособляется, но в некоторых случаях оно напоминает вводное слово, например:

Кое-где в Париже говорили в это время, что автора такой депеши **по-настоящему** следовало бы расстрелять . Работа шла уже часа три, и **по-настоящему** следовало бы идти домой.

Следует ли здесь обособить наречие "по-настоящему" и можно ли его вообще найти в словаре вводных слов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "по-настоящему"... можно ли его вообще найти в словаре вводных слов?

**Можно.**

См. ***Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений"***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Есть в списке вводных! См. пункт е)!

[Вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются или отделяются запятыми, когда...](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MpMc1ZIIC0cJ:orfogrammka.ru/%25D0%25BF%25D1%2583%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D1%2583%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F/%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D0%25B5_%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0_%25D0%25B8_%25D1%2581%25D0%25BE%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F_%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2/%20&cd=3&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)

> е) указывают на экспрессивный характер высказывания: без лести
>   сказать, если сказать правду, кроме шуток, между нами, между нами будь
>   сказано, между нами говоря, надо правду сказать, надо признаться, надо
>   сказать, не к ночи будь сказано, нечего сказать, по душе,
>   ***по-настоящему,*** по правде, по правде говоря, по правде сказать, по совести, по справедливости, правду говоря, правду сказать,
>   признаться, признаюсь, прямо скажем, скажу вам, скажу вам прямо,
>   сказать меж нами, сказать по совести, сказать по чести, смешно
>   сказать, уверяю вас, честно говоря.

В Ваших примерах "по-настоящему" легко заменимо на

*по правде сказать, по совести сказать, прямо скажем, скажу вам,* и другие варианты.

Необособленное "по-настоящему" просто ответит на вопрос "как?". Ответ: не по-игрушечному.

> Наречие зависит от глагола или другого наречия и отвечает на вопрос
>   как? Поступил (как?) по-деловому.

Comment: >> *В Ваших примерах "по-настоящему" легко заменимо на

по правде сказать, по совести сказать, прямо скажем, скажу вам, и другие варианты.* Если заменить на эти, то да. А вот если заменить, например, на "по большому счету" (что кажется мне точнее)?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в этих примерах *следует обособить* "по-настоящему" как вводное слово, иначе слово будет относиться не к характеристике действия в целом (как нужно поступить), а только к действию глагола (расстрелять не понарошку, как в прошлый раз, а на самом деле). Здесь "по-настоящему" относится **не к глаголу "расстрелять"**. Чтобы это выявить, "по-настоящему" можно без изменения смысла расширить таким оборотом (в нём "по-настоящему" относится к другому глаголу, который в сокращении до "по-настоящему" может подразумеваться):

```
... автора такой депеши, если поступать по-настоящему, следовало бы расстрелять.
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае обособлять не следует, так как это наречие. Расстрелять(как?) по-настоящему, расстрелять (как?) понарошку.
Во втором случае обособлять надо, так как это вводное слово, ведь здесь невозможно задать вопрос. Наверное, следовало бы идти домой; Действительно, следовало бы идти домой